# Implementing security in Fiware

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to deploy a Fiware-based system composed by Orion CB and some webapps, and I want to include security in this deployment by using the differents security GE availables.
OrionCB runs on Centos and (i.e)authorization-pdp-authzforce runs on Ubuntu TLS. Does this means that I need to use (i.e)two VPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AuthZForce is not supposed to be run on the same machine as Orion Context Broker. This doesn't mean that you can't, only that you are not *forced* to do it.

What would make more sense to run on the same machine (but still it is *not* a requirement) is to run a policy enforcement proxy. At the moment there are a couple that work with FIWARE:

- [FIWARE Wilma PEP Proxy](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy).
- [FIWARE Orion PEP](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep).

Both of them are developd using NodeJS, so they should run on a CentOS just fine. Keep in mind that even if you use AuthZForce you still need the a PEP proxy.